# Getting Key from a For loop with a List (not a Map)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a List of Models (List items) that I loop over in my template :

```
@for(item <- items) {
    // ...
}
```

I'd like to get the key/index position of the `item` in `items` for two reasons :

1. I will show something like `Item n° @key`
2. I'd like to show only 1/2 items (I suppose : `if (@key % 2)`)

How can I get the key/index if using a List and not a Map ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can zip the list with its indices:

```
@defining(List("foo", "bar", "baz")) { items => 
  @for((item, i) <- items.zipWithIndex if i % 2 == 0) {
    @item no @i <br/>
  }
}
```

Which prints:

```
foo no 0 
baz no 2
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use .zipWithIndex:

```
@for((item,i) <- items.zipWithIndex) {
    // ...
}
```

Index would be 0-based.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add a "counter" in the loop. Just declare it as a var before the loop, initialize it to 0, and increment it at the end of the loop.

The other option is to use zipWithIndex on your list before iterating over it. Then, instead of getting the items in the loop variable, you'll actually have a tuple made up of the item and its index in the list.